# Load a texture in List of Texture2D XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I created the

```
List<Texture2D> paddles = new List<Texture2D>();
```

and in the LoadContent() in the XNA, I wanted to load a single texture so I did it like this:

```
paddles[0] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics/First Paddle");
paddles[1] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics/Second Paddle");
```

but I have received this error at this line of code when I tried to run it `paddles[0] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics/First Paddle");`

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>        Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

How to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: You probably want to do something like : paddles.Add(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics/First Paddle")); Can someone confirm this? I have no access to my VS right now

Comment: But, is that the paddles just load a first paddle? What about if I want to load the first and second paddle?

Thanks

Comment: You would just duplicate the above line but replace "Graphics/First Paddle" to "Graphics/Second Paddle"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to reference list items that currently don't exist, and therefore, you're getting the given error. Try using the below:

```
paddles.Add(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Graphics/First Paddle"));
```

Note in the future that a list never has its objects instantiated, so you need to use Add to directly add to the list.

Comment: But, is that the paddles just load a first paddle? What about if I want to load the first and second paddle?

Thanks

Comment: Simply do the same again. They'll appear exactly like an array in a sense that you can use their indexes like arrays, but they work in a different way to an array and therefore when adding new items you'll need to use Add rather than directly assigning to an index.